# В чем проблема, выводится только одно значение, а не все по порядку. C++

Tags: c++, циклы

```
//Вводимые данные A - начало B - конец диапазона, r-шаг в диапазоне, e- кол-во знаков после запятой
//Выводит только последнее значение
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double fact(int N)
{
    if (N < 0)
        return 0;
    if (N == 0) 
        return 1; 
    else 
        return N * fact(N - 1);
}

double Summa(double eps, int i)
{
    double z;
    int j,one,p,f;
    f = 1;
    one = -1;
    if (i > 1)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++);
         {
            f *= (i * i);
         }
        if (i > 2)
        {
            for (p = 1; p <= i; p++);
            {
                one *= -1;
            }
        }
    }
    z = one * (f / fact(2 * i));
    return z;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int A, B, i, eps, r;
    double f;
    cout << "Введите значение A:"; cin >> A;
    cout << "Введите значение B:"; cin >> B;
    cout << "Введите значение r:"; cin >> r;
    cout << "Введите значение e:"; cin >> eps;
    cout.precision(eps); //ограничение знаков 
    cout << fixed;     //указание на ограничение после запятой
    cout << "\t X" << "\t f(X)" << endl;
    for (i = A; i < B; i+=r);
    {
        f=Summa(eps, i);
        cout << "\t " << i << "\t " << f << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Harry, наверное для того, чтобы цикл ничего не выполнял))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заколебали детские ошибки :)

Ну вот зачем тут точка с запятой???

```
for (i = A; i < B; i+=r);
```

В результате - **пустой** цикл, без тела...

Кстати, если бы вы объявляли переменные не как в С - в начале функции, а при использовании

```
for(int i.....
```

то ошибка выпрыгнула бы сразу!

И так - *в каждом цикле*... Я в шоке :(

Answer (score 1):

После каждого `for (;;); {}` находится точка с запятой после круглых скобок.
Этого не должно быть, если хотите, чтобы цикл работал так, как указали в скобках.

Уберите везде ";", вот пример(было):

```
for (j = 1; j <= i; j++);
{
    f *= (i * i);
}
```

Стало:

```
for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
{
    f *= (i * i);
}
```

Вот ваш код (уже отредактирован и работает):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double fact(int N)
{
    if (N < 0)
        return 0;
    if (N == 0) 
        return 1; 
    else 
        return N * fact(N - 1);
}

double Summa(double eps, int i)
{
    double z;
    int j,one,p,f;
    f = 1;
    one = -1;
    if (i > 1)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
         {
            f *= (i * i);
         }
        if (i > 2)
        {
            for (p = 1; p <= i; p++)
            {
                one *= -1;
            }
        }
    }
    z = one * (f / fact(2 * i));
    return z;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int A, B, i, eps, r;
    double f;
    cout << "Введите значение A:"; cin >> A;
    cout << "Введите значение B:"; cin >> B;
    cout << "Введите значение r:"; cin >> r;
    cout << "Введите значение e:"; cin >> eps;
    cout.precision(eps); //ограничение знаков 
    cout << fixed;     //указание на ограничение после запятой
    cout << "\t X" << "\t f(X)" << endl;
    for (i = A; i < B; i+=r);
    {
        f=Summa(eps, i);
        cout << "\t " << i << "\t " << f << endl;
    }
}
```